# HTTP Post Request data could not be read Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, http, post

I've been trying to get data by Http "POST" method.In my php script i have a key call "categoryWise" which has a value called "flower".I put all the necessary codes but it doesn't work and says The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.Please help.

```
    let values = "categoryWise= nature"

    let parameter = values.data(using: .utf8)


    let url = "https://mahadehasancom.000webhostapp.com/WallpaperApp/php_scripts/getImageByCategory.php"

    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = parameter

    request.setValue("application/x-content-type-options", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("application/x-content-type-options", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")


    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if (error != nil)
        {
            print(error!)
        }
        else
        {
            do
            {
                let fetchData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                //print(fetchData)
                let actorArray = fetchData?["result"] as? NSArray
                for actor in actorArray!
                {
                    let nameDict = actor as? NSDictionary

                    let name = nameDict?["date"] as! String
                    let countryname = nameDict?["category"] as! String
                    let imageUrl = nameDict?["url"] as! String
                    //let pageUrl = nameDict?["url"] as! String

                    authorArray.append(name)
                    titleArray.append(countryname)
                    imageURL.append(imageUrl)
                    //urlArray.append(pageUrl)

                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.CountryNameTable.reloadData()
                }

                print(authorArray)
                print(titleArray)
                print(imageURL)
                print(urlArray)
            }

            catch let Error2
            {
                print(Error2.localizedDescription)

                if let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8)
                {
                    print(string)
                    print(response!)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

Comment: @Rob
Thanks.By printing the string and response i get --> <html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
and 
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x6080002333e0> { URL: https://mahadehasancom.000webhostapp.com/WallpaperApp/php_scripts/getImageByCategory.php } { status code: 500, headers {
    "Content-Type" = "text/html";
    Date = "Fri, 26 May 2017 20:44:50 GMT";
    Server = awex;
} }
and for key-value, let values = "categoryWise=flower"

Comment: @Rob
Sorry brother.i actually don't understand the facts about 'request format' and Content-Type as i am new to this kind.Would you please help me solve this.I want to grab all the photos for value "flower" which key is "categoryWise".But i am unable to get the solution.Please help...

Comment: @Rob
here is the link for php code.please check & also i've edited my main swift code...
https://gist.github.com/saifaion/ebe7082f765c24352c05bd04444c9d41

Comment: Thanks Man.You are Brilliant.It's solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few observations:

1. You shared PHP that is using `$_POST`. That means it's expecting `x-www-form-urlencoded` request. So, in Swift, you should set `Content-Type` of the request to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` because that's what you're sending. Likewise, in Swift, the `Accept` of the request should be `application/json` because your code will "accept" (or expect) a JSON response.
2. The `values` string you've supplied has a space in it. There can be no spaces in the key-value pairs that you send in a `x-www-form-urlencoded` request. (Note, if you have any non-alphanumeric characters in your `values` key pairs, you should be percent encoding them.)
3. In your Swift error handler, in addition to printing the `error`, you might want to try converting the `data` to a `String`, and looking to see what it says, e.g.

   ```
   if let string = String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) {
       print(string)
   }
   ```
4. You might also want to look at `response` and see what `statusCode` it reported. Having done that, you subsequently told us that it reported a `statusCode` of 500.

   Status code 500 means that there was some internal error in the web service. (The code is 200 if successful.) This is generally a result of some error with the request not being handled correctly. For example, if the request neglected to format the request correctly and the web service doesn't anticipate/catch that, or if there was some other internal error on the web server, you could get 500 error code. For list of status codes, see http://w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html.
5. If the text in the body of the response from your web service is not illuminating, you might want to turn on error reporting (see [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) or [How do I catch a PHP Fatal Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277224/how-do-i-catch-a-php-fatal-error)) and then look at the body of the response again. For example, you might include the following in your PHP:

   ```
   <?php

   function __fatalHandler() {
       $error = error_get_last();
       //check if it's a core/fatal error, otherwise it's a normal shutdown
       if ($error !== NULL && in_array($error['type'], array(E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING))) {
           header("Content-Type: application/json");
           $result = Array("success" => false, "error" => $error);
           echo json_encode($result);
           die;
       }
   }
   register_shutdown_function('__fatalHandler');
   // the rest of your PHP here
   ?>
   ```

Comment: It's really amazing to get such informations for a beginner from You.I'll try tp keep all these things in my mind.Thanks again for the Suggestions.